# At the first collision of two bodies added 2 score. After another collision uz add only one score

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

**At the first collision of two bodies added 2 score. After another collision uz add only one score. How to fix it? Thank you**

Here is my Code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) 
{
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask 
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else 
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.monster != 0) &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.naboj != 0)) 
    {
        if let firstNode = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode,
                let secondNode = secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode  
        {
            projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstNode, monster: secondNode)
        };
        score = score + 1
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I have it :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the value of `score` before adding 1 into that at first collision. I am sure the value is already set to 1 while you adding 1 into it. so it is displaying 2 at first time and after that it increment it by 1.